# Grails template in intellij

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

In intellij when creating a controller for a domain it is generated with many methods likse
`save()`
`update()`
`edit()`
`delete()`

And I dont want that, so I made `grails install-templates` and I got the templates in source folder but I see the template for controller only have `index()` method.

Does intellij use another template? how to make intellij use my own template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you took a look to **src/templates/artifacts/Controller.groovy** but need to search in **src/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy**

Comment: but when I changed this so the newly created controller in intellij would be generated with minimal methods this affects the scaffold at runtime so if I use scaffold in controller it has nothing at runtime no view, create, delete, etc.. So is there a way to make intellij generate certain template but dont affect the grails scaffold feature at runtime?

Comment: put your custom templates to folder and then write you own script that create a controller from it